# How can I eject a memory card or other removable media from the command line (without removing the reader)?

Tags: windows-vista, sd-card, eject

I can eject a network drive using `net use X: /DELETE` but when I try to use this same command on removable media I get an error:

```
The network connection could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.
```

Yes, obviously it isn't a network connection, so how do I eject the device from a script?

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate of the other question. That question is about **removing** a USB device; this is about **ejecting** a removable media. Using the solutions in the other question will *remove* the drive which is not the same as *ejecting* the media in the drive. If you eject a memory-card from a card-reader, then you can take the card out and plug another one in and start using it. If you remove it, the whole reader will be removed and it will be a real pain to get it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesnt appear to be a built in Windows command to do this.  There may be scripting functionality in VBScript or PowerShell, but I didnt see any.

However, you are not the only person to ask this.  I found [this](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/52669-45-command-eject-mass-storage-device) in a quick Google search.  Some C++ code to compile to give you a CLI command to eject media.  Look at the first answer to the question for a link to the code.

Here is a precompiled [program](http://www.freeeject.com/) that does something similar.

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised this isn't possible without external software. I would rather just pull the card than have to go to all this trouble.

Comment: just be sure to enable "quick removal" so you dont corrupt your data

Comment: i'll make sure that's enabled.  however, it should be safe anyway if i'm not writing the drive, right? i'm basically just running an asset import script which only reads data off the device.

Comment: If you arent writing to the drive, in theory the cache doesnt need to be flushed... but you never know...  better safe than sorry, right?

Comment: It looks like the Freeject tool actually does eject removable media without removing the drive. Finally a solution. Thanks!